# Move Object on trigger using Unity's Visual Scripting

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers

I've created this mini just to try stuff out using unity's visual scripting. In my scene when the player (First Person Controller) can collide with a cube and when it does, it should trigger another object( a 3d model from mixamo) to move forward. Below is a preview of the scene.

[image]

Below is the visual script for the green cube that will trigger the character transformation.

[image]

Right now it doesn't work. I think the onUpdate event should be used but I don't know how to connect the nodes.

Comment: Doesn't it work even though I connect it as shown in the picture?

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Etim.png

Comment: The purpose of the visual  code is you can see what happens. You should be able to tell from that whats happening